# ¿como se puede optimizar un script de filtrado a un tabla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-tabla

Tengo la siguiente funcion en JavaScript para filtrar datos de una tabla, pero su tiempo de respuesta mientras voy escribiendo el dato a buscar es muy lento, hay alguna forma para optimizarlo?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, jQuery ya tiene la opción para filtrar datos y es muy sencilla de utilizar.

Tan simple como agregar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buscar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tablaCotizaciones1 tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Nota que agrego la función en el "keyup" the el texto $("#buscar"), o sea que va buscando en "tiempo real" por así llamarlo

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias, lo mio funcionaba pero se demoraba en cargar y estaba buscando otra alternativa para que su ejecución fuera mas optima.

Comment: Excelente! que bien que te srivió